# Make the desktop look like 3D in Windows 7 and XP

Tags: windows-7

I found a program in the past that can make the desktop look like it's 3D. Basically it's not the [3D Aero flip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero#Aero_animation) that I'm talking about. It's a program that can make your screen look like it's spherical or make it look like it's a cube. If you have 6 windows that are currently open the software will make it like a cube. And you can turn it around. Do you know what that software is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SphereXP** - the world's number one three-dimensional desktop.

[image]

**[YODM 3D](http://yodm-3d.uptodown.com/en/)** - Virtual Desktop Manager featuring the Cube 3D effect

[image]

**[Matodate](http://madotate.en.softonic.com/)** - Manage windows more easily in a 3D desktop

[image]

**[BumpTop™](http://bumptop.com/)** is a fun, intuitive 3D desktop that keeps you organized and makes you more productive.

[image]

Comment: is this free my friend?

Comment: @user23950 - depending on the version, Yodm 3.14 is free, Matodate and SphereXP are free, BumpTop is available as free and pro (paid).

Comment: +1 molly  :) I don't see it . But I often recommend the best , so people don't take time to research others ;)

Comment: @nXqd - ummm, the question wasn't exactly about recommendations, the OP was using a program before and couldn't remember the name :)

Comment: Seems that BumpTop (for both Windows and Mac) will no longer be available for sale. Additionally, no updates to the products are planned.

Comment: @slhck you can still download it from PC World, it just isn't being maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Shock 4Way3D](http://www.docs.kr/entry/Download-Shock-4Way3D-en)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try the best: [BumpTop](http://bumptop.com/).

[image]

It's been recommended a lot!

Comment: Woah, what is that picture? Multiple desktop support or just a fancy screenshot collection?

Comment: @jay - this is just a collage, for a 'proper' screen shot of BumpTop, see the last recommendation my answer :)

Comment: This is acquired by Google! This means that BumpTop (for both Windows and Mac) will no longer be available.